# How can I build litecoin from source in Visual Studio (2010 or 2012)?

Tags: litecoin

I am curious if anyone has successfully built and linked all dependencies for litecoin and, finally, built litecoin in Visual Studio.

If so, could someone please provide some instructions on how to do this?  I'd like to run some tests and I'm quite familiar with the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score -1):

its a fork of bitcoin so this should be the same https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=24670.0